# Generate unique combinations for A, B, C using Ruby or Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, combinations, permutation

I have three groups:

```
Group A = 4
Group B = 8
Group C = 11
```

For each group, if I add an additional item, for example:

```
Group A = 4;
Group A Additional = 2;

Group B = 8;
Group B Additional = 3;

Group C = 10;
Group C Additional = 3;
```

I need to add the additional depending on how many groups are available.
Example:

```
A = 4
AA = 6 (4 + 2)
AAA = 8 (4 + 2 + 2) here I have A and 2 additional items

B = 8
BB = 11 (8 + 3)
BBB = 14 (8 + 3 + 3)

Same for C...
```

I need to generate all possible combinations of these groups with the correct values.

This should be the result:

```
A, AA, AAA
B, BA, BAA, BB, BBA, BBB
C, CA, CAA, CB, CBA, CBB, CC, CCA, CCB, CCC
```

If AAA is 8 (4 + 2 + 2) and BBB = 14 (8 + 3 + 3)
I want:

```
CBA to be 22 (10 + 8 + 4)
CBB to be (10 + 8 + 8)
```

and so on.

This is what I made until now.

```
items = [
  { :group => "A", :value=> 4, :add => 2 },
  { :group => "B", :value=> 8, :add => 3 },
  { :group => "C", :value=> 10, :add => 3 },
]

def process(items)
  array = []

  items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  counter = 0
    (1..3).each do |vari|
      el = item[:group] * vari

      if vari == 1 
        value = item[:value]
      else 
        value = item[:value] + (item[:add] * counter)
      end

      puts "#{el}:  #{value}"

      array.push(el)
      counter = counter + 1
    end
  end
  array
end
```

It only works for 
A, AA, AAA
B, BB, BBB
C, CC, CCC

Output:

```
A:  4
AA:  6
AAA:  8
B:  8
BB:  11
BBB:  14
C:  10
CC:  13
CCC:  16
```

Can anyone help to complete the script?

Comment: I understand how the letters should be converted to a number, but I can't figure out where `A, AA, AAA
B, BA, BAA, BB, BBA, BBB
C, CA, CAA, CB, CBA, CBB, CC, CCA, CCB, CCC` comes from. Is this a given? Or do you calculate it from A (4,2) B (8,3) C(10,3) some way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an recursive approach by taking the index for the next call of the function.

This solution takes a dummy item for getting single or double combination.

```js
function c(array, size) {

    function iter(i, p) {
        var temp = p.join('');
        if (i >= array.length) {
            return;
        }
        if (p.length === size) {
            temp && result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        iter(i + 1, p);
        iter(i, p.concat(array[i]));
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var values = { A: { value: 4, add: 2 }, B: { value: 8, add: 3 }, C: { value: 10, add: 3 } },
    combinations = c(['C', 'B', 'A', ''], 3),
    result = combinations.map(s => [...s].reduce(
        (r, k, i, a) => r + values[k][['value', 'add'][+(k === a[i - 1])]],
        0
    ));

console.log(combinations);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, ruby:

```
w = {:a=>[4, 2], :b=>[8, 3], :c=>[10, 3], nil =>[0, 0]}
[1, 2, 3].flat_map do |count|
  %i[a b c].repeated_combination(count).map do |a, b, c|
    [
      [a, b, c].join.upcase,
      a == b ? 
        w[a].first + (b == c ? w[a].last * 2 : w[a].last + w[c].first) :
        [w[a], w[b], w[c]].map(&:first).reduce(:+)
    ]
  end
end.to_h

#⇒ {"A"=>4, "B"=>8, "C"=>10,
#   "AA"=>6, "AB"=>12, "AC"=>14, "BB"=>11, "BC"=>18, "CC"=>13,
#   "AAA"=>8, "AAB"=>14, "AAC"=>16, "ABB"=>20, "ABC"=>22,
#      "ACC"=>24, "BBB"=>14, "BBC"=>21, "BCC"=>28, "CCC"=>16}
```